# How can I build esm5 build for a library with Angular Cli v11?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I created a library `angular11-lib` with angular cli inside a workspace.

I generated the build with `ng build angular11-lib --prod`.

In dist, I have the following folders:

```
bundles
esm2015
fesm2015
lib
```

There isn't an `esm5` build in a folder that was present when using the older cli version.

How can I generate an `esm5` build with this cli so that I can use the library in IE11?

Comment: What is inside bundles..?

Comment: angular11-lib.umd.js. I know it's possible to use the umd file, but I was trying to get the esm5 bundle was used to be present before.

Comment: It seems it’s just no longer needed: https://volosoft.com/blog/what-is-new-in-angular-10

Comment: It's not needed if I use the library in an Angular 11 application. However, if I use the library in an angular8 or angular 9 application, the library doesn't render in ie11. Not sure if there's a workaround for this issue.

Comment: I’m not sure if you can compile with 11 and still use it for older, non-ivy apps. I don’t think you can unless they fixed that recently...